# For Rails app, how find which string fields have "old" (255) default char limits, since Rails changed the default limit AND removed it from schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, varchar

How can one find *which* string fields in a Rails/Postgres database still have the old default 255 char limit maximum size, since over time Rails has not only introduced inconsistent default string sizes, but *also* removed that information from the schema.rb file?

We need to know which "old" string fields we need to migrate to `:string, limit: nil` to match the "newer" `string` fields.

The problem is that some "new" tables and fields were created while the app was using Rails 4.2 but many of the "old" tables and fields where created using earlier Rails versions.

And unfortunately at some point Rails not only stopped putting the default string limit in the schema.rb file, but Rails *also* changed the limit for strings from 255 to a *much* larger value.

The end result is that some "old" `string` fields in the production database hold 255 chars, while other "new" `string` fields can hold whatever the current default is (about 1GB I think)... **but the schema.rb file no longer indicates which is which.**

So recreating a new database then loading the schema via `rake db:schema:load` (in the test environment for example) will yield a *significantly different Test database* than the production database that evolved through migrations. Which leads to Test specs that would pass although the same code might fail in production due to inconsistent sizes of the exact same `string` field in the Test and Production databases.

As a simple example, copying a `string` field from Table A to Table B might work in Test and in Production, whereas copying the *same* fields the other direction from Table B to Table A could work in Test but *fail* in production if Table A is an 'old' table created with 255 char limit fields while Table B has much larger string maximum.

Comment: Switch from a Ruby schema to a SQL schema by setting `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`. While the portability of a Ruby schema is nice in theory this is usually inevitable if you want to use a lot of postgres specific features.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.reject(&:abstract_class?).each do |klass|
  klass.columns_hash.each do |column,options|
    next unless options.sql_type_metadata.type == :string # might have to modify this
    
    # ... some logic here to look at options.sql_type_metadata.sql_type or options.sql_type_metadata.limit  
  end
end
```

What you're looking for is on `ModelName.columns_hash` inside the `sql_type_metadata` method.